# android - using resources drawable in content provider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-resources

I am trying to pass back an image through a content provider in a separate app. I have two apps, one with the activity in (app a), the other with content provider (app b)

I have app a reading an image off my SD card via app b using the following code.

App a:

```
public void but_update(View view)
{
    ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.jash.cp_source_two.provider/note/1");
    InputStream inStream = null;

    try
    {
        inStream = resolver.openInputStream(uri);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inStream);
        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "error = "+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
    }

    finally {
        if (inStream != null) {
            try {
                inStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("test", "could not close stream", e);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

App b:

```
@Override
public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(Uri uri, String mode)
       throws FileNotFoundException {   
    try
    {
        File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(),"pic2.png");
        return ParcelFileDescriptor.open(path,ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
            Log.i("r", "File not found");
            throw new FileNotFoundException();
    }
}
```

In app a I am able to display an image from app a's resources folder, using setImageURi and constructing a URI using the following code.

```
int id = R.drawable.a2;
Resources resources = getBaseContext().getResources(); 
Uri uri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + 
resources.getResourcePackageName(id) + '/' + 
resources.getResourceTypeName(id) + '/' + 
resources.getResourceEntryName(id) );
image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
image.setImageURI(uri);
```

However, if I try to do the same in app b (read from app b's resources folder rather than the image on the SD card) it doesn't work, saying it can't find the file, even though I am creating the path of the file from the resource, so it is definitely there.

Any ideas? Does it restrict sending resources over the content provider somehow?

P.S. I also got an error when I tried to create the file with

`File path = new File(uri);` saying 'there is no applicable constructor to '`(android.net.Uri)`' though http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#File(java.net.URI) Seems to think it's possible...unless java.net.URI is different to android.net.URI, in which case can I convert them?

Thanks

Russ

Answer (score 0):

android.net.URI doesn't exist. There is an android.net.Uri (note the spelling). This is not the same as java.net.URI. You can probably convert a Uri to a String and then to a URI.

So, you can open a file on your SD card (or so you claim), and you can set an image in your main Activity (or so you claim). I don't see that your you're getting back an image or anything else from a content provider?

A content provider stores data. It can return files (that is, file descriptors), including file descriptors for asset files, but it has nothing to do with Resources in your application.

Comment: Ok, so I didn't include the code that calls and uses the content provider I pasted at the beginning.

Comment: Have added it above.

Are you saying I can't pass images from resources back across a content provider? (All be it via a ParcelFileDescriptor)?

What is the difference between ParcelFileDescriptor and AssetFileDescriptor?

I'm happy to put my images in the assets folder but i thought resources was the preferred place for them?

Comment: The resources I'm talking about using in my example were in my main app, but I want to use the resources folder in the content provider app, sorry if that wasn't clear